# Stroke not overlapping the shape

Tags: android, xml, shapes

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#ff898d" />

    <stroke
        android:width="5dp"
        android:color="#B3ffffff" />

    <size
        android:height="76dp"
        android:width="330dp" />

</shape>
```

I want to make a shape with stroke by the xml in native android API. The stroke has opacity. After making the opacity, I found the stroke has overlapped the shape. Therefore, there are three colours in the shape. (Actually one is the shape itself, one is stoke, and one is the overlapping area). Therefore, how can I make them not overlapping?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40169488/prevent-partial-overlapping-of-shape-drawable-stroke