# prevent partial overlapping of shape drawable stroke

Tags: android, android-shapedrawable

Is there any way to prevent partial overlapping of the `stroke` on the `shape drawable`. I prefer to overlap the stroke completely on the borders of the shape.

Here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <padding
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/green" />
    <stroke android:color="@color/red_50"
        android:width="20dp"
        android:dashGap="2dp"
        android:dashWidth="10dp" />
</shape>
```

**colors.xml**

```
<color name="green">#0f0</color>
<color name="red_50">#8f00</color>
```

And here is what is achieved
[image: Sample Image]

As you can see that the stroke is overlapping the solid part by 50% but I want it to be 100%.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to divide it into two shapes - one for ***stroke*** and one for ***rectangle***.  In this solution I manipulate size of rectangle so that I can change its relation with borders.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:bottom="@dimen/offset"
        android:left="@dimen/offset"
        android:right="@dimen/offset"
        android:top="@dimen/offset">

        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/green" />
        </shape>

    </item>

    <item>

        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="20dp"
                android:color="@color/red_50"
                android:dashGap="2dp"
                android:dashWidth="10dp" />
        </shape>

    </item>

</layer-list>
```

You can adjust the offset to get **outer or inner stroke**.

[image: Outer & inner stroke]

These values come from difference of size of ***transparent rectangle*** (stroke layer) and ***the green one***. In your case they will be `20dp` or none.

Comment: In case B isn't padding of the filled rectangle zero? Since there is no stroke to accommodate for.

Comment: @EugenPechanec If there is no offset we get the result shown in question - green rect starts _half of stroke's width_. That is why we have to increase its bounds by this value (by subtracting '_padding_').

Comment: But the whole point of your post is that the green rectangle *has no stroke* so it fills the whole available area therefore does not need a negative offset, is it not? (I.e. if you need to offset green rectangle by 20dp to accommodate for 20dp wide stroke, then you need 20-20=0dp offset to draw green underneath the stroke.)

Comment: @EugenPechanec You're right. I've edited the answer. Do you agree with it now? I missed it while testing - it looked proper, but indeed your suggestion is correct :)

Comment: Yup, looks good now. (Note: The original would cause 10dp extra green space around the view if its parent had `android:clipChildren="false"`.)