# Shape with outer stroke only

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="oval"
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>

    <stroke android:width="30dp"
            android:color="#51000000"
        />
</shape>
```

It gives a "half-inner-half-outer" stroke.
What I need is outer semitransparent stroke only. Can it be done?

What I have is
[image: What I have]

What I need is
[image: What I need]

Thanks

Comment: Please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40219413/3998710 It really works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found no way to do that other than the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                android:width="@dimen/stroke_width"
                android:color="#33000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item >
        <shape android:shape="oval" >
            <solid android:color="#fff" />
            <stroke
                android:width="@dimen/stroke_width"
                android:color="@android:color/transparent">
            </stroke>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can check this shape created using layer list with it's items.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="oval" >
            <solid android:color="#fff" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item >
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                android:width="50dp"
                android:color="#30000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: That gives just a ring with no solid white color inside.

Comment: can you add image how do you want ?

Comment: It gives inner stroke, not outer.

Comment: Just change the color there is no inner and outer stroke.

Comment: change color to #80000000 and check.

Comment: I have checked before writing the comment above. Also, I know how to get the result with the layer-list. The question is it possible to achieve that with just a single shape?

Answer (score 0):

if you add alpha for stroke color the inner half is without transparent and outer is transparent.this is how stroke color works.if you don't want inner circle use color without Alpha and adjust Hexcode.

Comment: Can you provide a reference from where you get that?

Comment: "the inner half is without transparent and outer is transparent" - can you see the attached image? The both halfs are transparent. Also, could you provide a markup, plz?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding android:innerRadius="0dp" for shape attribute -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="oval"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:innerRadius="0dp"
>
<solid android:color="#ffffff"/>

<stroke android:width="4dp"
    android:color="#51000000"
    />
</shape>
```

Comment: nothing is changed. the result is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is Android studio XML preview bug.look like The image you shown above from Android studio xml preview.actually there is no inner and outer layer.

Comment: what api level?

Comment: I have no real device with me right now. However, the emulator shows exactly the same result as the preview does. So most likely the result will be the same on a real device as well.

Comment: [Screen shot of my result.the circle in top have a stroke with Alpha value](http://imgur.com/a/X2XiK)

Comment: It's just a screenshot. Show the corresponding markup, plz.

Answer (score 0):

Try This: (Change dimens and colors to fit your needs)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke android:width="@dimen/default_stroke_size_small" android:color="@color/colorDimBlack"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke android:width="@dimen/default_stroke_size_small" android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score -1):

update your code to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

    <stroke
        android:width="30dp"
        android:color="#000000" /> <--- this line you have to change
</shape>
```

Comment: Changing the output color isn't what OP wants!

Comment: "this line you have to change" - No. I need a semitransparent stroke.

Answer (score -2):

You are missing one `f` in your first color. Thus it's creating a half visible pattern

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="oval"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <solid android:color="#fffffff"/>

    <stroke android:width="30dp"
        android:color="#51000000"
        />
</shape>
```